# how can I change css within a nested jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml

I'm trying to create an element which when the mouse is over its image changes and it's position is adjusted accordingly. However the image is changing but the css position isn't changing.

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
        var newComment = $('<span>').attr({'id': commentCount}); 
        newComment
            .addClass('comment')  
            .css({
                'top': (yOffset * 100) + 175 + "px",
                'left': (xOffset * 75) + 40 + "px"
            })

            .hover(function(){ //Hover over the comment                       
                newComment

                .removeClass()
                .addClass('commentOver')
                .offset({
                    'top': yOffsets[newComment.id] + 175 - 1250 + "px",
                    'left': xOffsets[newComment.id] + 40 - 1500 + "px"
                });

            },function(){ //Mouse leaves the comment               
                newComment    

                .removeClass()
                .addClass('comment')
                .offset({
                    'top': yOffsets[newComment.id] + 1750 + "px",
                    'left': xOffsets[newComment.id] + 400 + "px" 
                });                      
            });
```

**CSS:**

```
.comment{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 51px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url('../img/dropSmall.png');
    font-weight:800;
}
```

Can you see where i'm going wrong and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the newComment span been added to the document?

Since we don't have the rest of your HTML/CSS/code, I don't know if these are the only issues, but I would suggest using $(this) and passing a parameter in removeClass():

```
    var newComment = $('<span>').attr({'id': commentCount}); 
    newComment
        .addClass('comment')  
        .css({
            'top': (yOffset * 100) + 175 + "px",
            'left': (xOffset * 75) + 40 + "px"
        })

        .hover(function(){ //Hover over the comment                       
            $(this)
            .removeClass("comment")
            .addClass('commentOver')
            .offset({
                'top': yOffsets[newComment.id] + 175 - 1250,
                'left': xOffsets[newComment.id] + 40 - 1500
            });

        },function(){ //Mouse leaves the comment               
            $(this)
            .removeClass("commentOver")
            .addClass('comment')
            .offset({
                'top': yOffsets[newComment.id] + 1750,
                'left': xOffsets[newComment.id] + 400" 
            });                      
        });
```

I don't see in the jQuery documentation where you can call removeClass() with no parameters passed.  It says you need one or more classes.

In addition the offset() method does not need units if the units are px.

You may also want to look at [toggleClass("a", "b")](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), which makes it easy to swap two classes.

Comment: if you call the `removeClass()` method without any parameters, it empties the class attribute. try it : `$(selector).removeClass().attr('class');`. it should return an empty string.

Comment: It may do that, but the documentation doesn't say that is allowed - in fact it says the parameter should be one or more class names.  I stay away from things that the documentation explicitly doesn't support.  `toggleClass()` is probably the right solution here anyway or just set `this.className = "";`.

Comment: i know it's not documented, but it is like a pattern. look at how other jquery methods act when called without arguments : `unbind(/* all events*/)`, `die('/*all events*/')`, `get(/*no index=> all the elements*/)`

Comment: @gion_13 - Slightly different case.  The `unbind()` documentation documents that you can call it with no parameters to remove all - the `removeClass()` doc does not.  In the spirit of safe code, I avoid using forms of parameters that are not advised in the documentation, particularly when there are documented ways to accomplish the same thing.  You're free to make different choices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you position the element `newComment` `absolute`?
You can't use top and left if the element is positioned `static`.

If you didn't, try this instead of your current `.css`:

```
.css({
      'top': (yOffset * 100) + 175 + "px",
      'left': (xOffset * 75) + 40 + "px",
      'position': 'absolute'
})
```

By the way: You don't have to pass the name of the css property as a string, when you write in DOM like. So this should work just the same:

```
.css({
     top: (yOffset * 100) + 175 + "px",
     left: (xOffset * 75) + 40 + "px",
     position: 'absolute'
})
```

Comment: I've used the following CSS for the comment element:
.comment{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 51px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url('../img/dropSmall.png');
    font-weight:800;    
}

Answer (score 0):

remove the "px" at the end of the offset object parameter ;)

```
.offset({
                'top': yOffsets[newComment.id] + 175 - 1250,// + "px",
                'left': xOffsets[newComment.id] + 40 - 1500// + "px"
            });
```

If the offset method does not recognize the `left` and `top` properties as a number, it does not update the element position.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't make a difference, i'm guessing the issue is something to do with the .offset method being called within a nested function and it's keeping the original left + top css positioning